# Is there some trick to override a class dynamically in PHP?

Tags: php, class, overriding

I have two class named `test` in two different files,`a.php` and `b.php` for instance,the logic is like this:

```
include('a.php');
$a = new test();
if($somcondition_is_met)
{
    include('b.php');
    $b = new test();
}
```

Is there some trick to avoid `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class` ?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php
1)

Answer (score 1):

classkit_import() looks like it does exactly what you want

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.classkit-import.php

From the link:

### Example #1 classkit_import() example

newclass.php

```
<?php
class Example {
    function foo() {
        return "bar!\n";
    }
}
?>
```

main.php

```
<?php
// requires newclass.php (see above)
class Example {
    function foo() {
        return "foo!\n";
    }
}

$e = new Example();

// output original
echo $e->foo();

// import replacement method
classkit_import('newclass.php');

// output imported
echo $e->foo();

?>
```

The above example will output:
foo!
bar!

Answer (score 1):

With "standard" PHP, no, you cannot do such a thing.

Still, looking at PECL and the manual, a possibility would be to use the **[classkit extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/classkit)** -- but it's marked as "*not maintained*", and has not been updated since 2004... So I would definitly not use it.

Quoting the PECL's page of that extension :

> NOTICE: **This package has been
>   discontinued**. Please refer to the
>   runkit package which is fully BC with
>   classkit and contains additional
>   functionality.

So, let's take a look at the **[runkit extension](http://fr.php.net/runkit)**, which might do the trick -- especially, the [`runkit_import`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-import.php) function could interest you *(quoting)* :

> Similar to `include()` however any
>   code residing outside of a function or
>   class is simply ignored. Additionally,
>   depending on the value of flags ,
>   **any functions or classes which already exist in the currently running
>   environment will be automatically
>   overwritten** by their new
>   definitions.

Still, note that, officially *(looking at it's [PECL page](http://pecl.php.net/package/runkit))*, the runkit extension has not been updated since 2006... Which is not a good sign either... Especially when it comes to PHP 5.3 support...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use Interfaces, rather then overwriting classes dynamicaly.

In your code you reference/use the interface class, and than you can have multiple classes that implement that interface.

Check the doc for more details on interfaces.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php